# How can I rename docker-compose.yml containers group in docker desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've built a *docker-compose.yml* file however I see by default Docker Desktop App names the group of containers by parent folder name.

[image]

I need to change that name *docker* to another name

This's my file explorer path:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME**

> Sets the project name. This value is prepended along with the service
> name to the container on start up. For example, if your project name
> is myapp and it includes two services db and web, then Compose starts
> containers named myapp_db_1 and myapp_web_1 respectively.
>
> Setting this is optional. If you do not set this, the
> COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME defaults to the basename of the project
> directory.

You can either set it by mentioning it in the .*env* file or while executing the docker-compose file.

**By mentioning it in .*env* file**

Create a `.env` file in the directory where docker-compose file is present and add the following statement.

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = <project_name>
```

**By mentioning it while executing the docker-compose file with the help of flag `-p`**

```
docker-compose -f <docker_compose_file> -p "<project_name>" up
```

Answer (score 24):

declare `name` in the `docker-compose.yml` file and make sure to run as `docker compose ...` not `docker-compose ...`. source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1123#issuecomment-1130002420

```yaml
name: project-name
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
```

Comment: I guess this must be new, because I haven't seem this approach anywhere in the web and have just discovered it by playing around with `docker compose convert`. Anyway, it works like a charm.

Comment: yes, @RicardoPassos, in the v2 of `docker compose` they changed their CLI command. I also didn't know this. This is why I always prefer reading the official documentation first.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `-p` flag with docker-compose up, let's say you want to name your app **stack-example**

```
docker-compose -p="stack-example" up
```

Comment: When using the [`-p`/`--profile-name` flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) you have to specify it with every `docker-compose` command. Alternatively you can set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) in your shell or even in your [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) in the project directory.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. @acran
Could you please set it as an answer to my question?

Comment: How do you rename an existing container group.  I don't want to destroy the old.  Does docker-compose not create a NEW instance, not rename the old?

Comment: If you are using `container_name` for a container in your compose config starting the stack a second time with either `docker-compose up -p.="my_stack" up` or `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foo docker-compose up`  you will get an error telling **The container name "/cname" is already in use...** , so I don't think there is a way for now using docker compose as I looked around you can read more about [compose_project_name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host).

Comment: @justdan0227 The thing behind containers project name is a `label` with key-value **com.docker.compose.project=projectname** maybe that could help.

Comment: @AffesSalem thanks but how do I do that on a project contain there is already created? aka rename

Comment: For now I don't think there's a possible way I could think about unless you will have to remove then recreate the container.